# Show user information depending condition?

Tags: php, oop

I have get an object `User`, that has filed `account_type`.

Also there is a class `Menu`, that shows menu items depending type account:

```
class Menu {

    private $menu = [];

    public function __construct(){
       $this->menu = [1 => [1 => "Menu1", 2=> "Menu2" ], 2=> [1=> "Menu3"]]
    }  

    public function getMenu($typeAccount){
       return $this->menu[$typeAccount];
    }

}
```

So, I fetch all menu items from array by `$typeAccount`.

It looks awful and don't scalable, can you recommend more OOP realization?

Comment: Does the Menu class have any other methods besides `getMenu` that do any other menu-related things, or is it just basically a wrapper around the array of menus?

Comment: Yes, I fixed it was mistake

Comment: Menu has additional parameeters as: groupId, url, title. It is not matter

Comment: You can also check using array key exists if its in the menu array before returning anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not scalable because the model contains data. So if you want to add or change menus associated with different account types, you'll have to alter your application code.

You need to store the data that defines the different menus in some external data source instead - a configuration file, a database, whatever works best for you.

When you remove the data from your code, then you can have a Menu class that's only responsible for being a Menu. You can pass all the data it needs in order to be a specific type of menu to its constructor.

```
class Menu {

    private $menu_items;

    function __construct($menu_items)
    {
        $this->menu_items = $menu_items;
        // set other menu properties as needed
    }

    // various methods related to being a menu
}
```

You can create another class that provides access to your external data source, and has a method that creates Menu objects based on a given account type.

```
class MenuRepository {

    private $data_source;

    public function __construct($data_source) {
        $this->data_source = $data_source;
    }

    public function getMenuItemsForAccountType($typeAccount)
    {
        $menu_items = $this->data_source->someQuery($typeAccount);
        return new Menu($menu_items);
    }

}
```

The specific implementation is really up to you, and this example may not even be that useful to you. But the main point, in my opinion, is that your application code is not the right place to store dynamic data.